# Issue w/ Bootstrap collapse/Bootstrap Modal/stopPropagation & HTML content exceeding height of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using Bootstrap Javascript component Collapse and Modal. I have added a simple clickable element to open a modal within the Collapse header. I use jQuery's stopPropagation to stop the click event of the collapse  from bubbling to the Bootstrap Javascipt callback. I have purposely left most of the rows uncollapsed in my Jsfiddle because my issue only happens when there is content that goes past the height of the viewing screen.

My problem is that the content shifts when I click my edit button and the collapse row that I click to edit is no longer visible on the screen:

http://jsfiddle.net/j22kf/

```
  $(function () {
      $(".collapse").collapse();

      $(".accordion").find('.btnEdit').click(function (ev) {
            ev.stopPropagation()
       });
      $(".btnEdit").click(function () {
             //ev.stopPropagation();
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
      });
  });

<div class="accordion" id="accordions">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"><a href="#group-1" data-parent="#accordions" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">Accordion Group 1&nbsp;<span class="btnEdit"><i class="icon-edit"></i>Click here to see issue</span></a>

        </div>
        <div id="group-1" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus egestas
                    tempor vulputate. Donec auctor libero eu justo eleifend eget dapibus mauris
                    blandit. Mauris faucibus elementum mauris, a vehicula elit auctor ut. Ut
                    pellentesque faucibus tempor. Curabitur a nisi purus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"><a href="#group-2" data-parent="#accordions" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">Accordion Group 2</a>

        </div>
        <div id="group-2" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus egestas
                    tempor vulputate. Donec auctor libero eu justo eleifend eget dapibus mauris
                    blandit. Mauris faucibus elementum mauris, a vehicula elit auctor ut. Ut
                    pellentesque faucibus tempor. Curabitur a nisi purus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a href="#group-3" data-parent="#accordions" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">Accordion Group 3</a>

        </div>
        <div id="group-3" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus egestas
                    tempor vulputate. Donec auctor libero eu justo eleifend eget dapibus mauris
                    blandit. Mauris faucibus elementum mauris, a vehicula elit auctor ut. Ut
                    pellentesque faucibus tempor. Curabitur a nisi purus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour">
        Collapsible Group 4
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus egestas
                    tempor vulputate. Donec auctor libero eu justo eleifend eget dapibus mauris
                    blandit. Mauris faucibus elementum mauris, a vehicula elit auctor ut. Ut
                    pellentesque faucibus tempor. Curabitur a nisi purus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFive">
        Collapsible Group 5
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus egestas
                    tempor vulputate. Donec auctor libero eu justo eleifend eget dapibus mauris
                    blandit. Mauris faucibus elementum mauris, a vehicula elit auctor ut. Ut
                    pellentesque faucibus tempor. Curabitur a nisi purus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse6">
        Collapsible Group 6
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse6" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus egestas
                    tempor vulputate. Donec auctor libero eu justo eleifend eget dapibus mauris
                    blandit. Mauris faucibus elementum mauris, a vehicula elit auctor ut. Ut
                    pellentesque faucibus tempor. Curabitur a nisi purus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse7">
        Collapsible Group 7
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse7" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse8">
        Collapsible Group 8
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse8" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse9">
        Collapsible Group 9
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse9" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse10">
        Collapsible Group 10
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse10" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse11">
        Collapsible Group 11
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse11" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the browser from trying to scroll to the "#" anchor:

```
  $(".btnEdit").click(function (ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
```